# contact form to download file and save info in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, contacts

To keep it simple this is what im trying to acheive.

1. user fills in the form
2. fields are validated if filled properly
3. when form submitted, check for all validation, if not then show error, if yes
4. email form details to my email
5. store same details into mysql database
6. show thank you message
7. download pdf file from within the folder

I've managed to do all of that but im facing one issue. when user click on download button without filling anything, they get an error but an empty row is added to the database. If they fill incorrect form they still see an error, but now there are 2 rows in the database. AND if they fill everything correctly, they see thanks you message and also get to download the file but it still add 2 rows in the table.

 how can i fix it? :(

here is code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#download").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });         
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="banner" class="clearfix">
    <div class="center">
        <a id="download" class="download" href="#FormLightBox"><img src="img/button-download.png" width="218" height="49" alt="Download" /></a>
        <p>(Your contact details will be required)</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="FormLightBox">
        <div class="inner">

            <h3 id="status" style="color:#F00; display:none;">Your Errors Here</h3>
            <h3>Leave your details below to download your free Guide pdf file</h3>        
            <p><input type="text" id="name" class="input-text" placeholder="Name"/></p>
            <p><input type="text" id="email" class="input-text" placeholder="E-mail"/></p>
            <p><input type="text" id="postcode" class="input-text" placeholder="Postcode"/></p>
            <p><input type="text" id="phone" class="input-text" placeholder="Telephone" onkeypress="return validnum(event)" /></p>
            <p><input type="image" id="i" class="input-button" src="img/button-download-lager.png" onclick="getResponse()"/></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get(y){
        return document.getElementById(y).value;
    }
    function getResponse(){
        $.get("process.php", { name: get('name'), email: get('email'), postcode: get('postcode'), phone: get('phone') },
           function(data){
             if(data.status === false || data.status === 'false'){
                 return errorMsg(data.message);
             }else{
                errorMsg(data.message);
                setTimeout(" offerDownloadAndClose()", 4000); 
             }
           }, "json");
    }
    function errorMsg(msg){
        $('#status').html(msg);
        $('#status').slideDown('slow');
        setTimeout("doHide('#status')", 3000);
    }
    function doHide(t){
        $(t).slideUp('slow');   
    }
    function offerDownloadAndClose(){
        doHide('#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-overlay');
        window.location = 'process.php?file=true';
    }
    function validnum(evt){
        var charCode;
        charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 46 || charCode == 127 || charCode == 8)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in my process.php

```
 <?php error_reporting(0);

if(empty($_GET)){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the complete form'));    
    exit;
}
//database insertion
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql_user","mysql_pwd");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mysql_database", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO formdata (name, email, postcode, phone) VALUES ('$_GET[name]','$_GET[email]','$_GET[postcode]','$_GET[phone]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);

// download function
if(isset($_GET['file'])){
$filename = 'Guide.pdf'; // set absolute relative path to this file
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/download/";
$fullpath = $path.$filename;
// required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($fullpath));
readfile($fullpath);
}

if(!isset($_GET['name']) || empty($_GET['name'])){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the name'));
    exit;
}elseif(strlen($_GET['name']) < 3){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the valid name (minimum 3 cherecters)'));
    exit;
}
if(!isset($_GET['email']) || empty($_GET['email'])){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the email'));
    exit;
}elseif(!ereg('[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+', $_GET['email'])){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Invalid email address'));
    exit;
}
if(!isset($_GET['postcode']) || empty($_GET['postcode']) || strlen($_GET['postcode']) < 3){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the postcode'));
    exit;
}
if(!isset($_GET['phone']) || empty($_GET['phone']) || strlen($_GET['phone']) < 11){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the phone'));
    exit;
}elseif(strlen(str_replace(' ', '',$_GET['phone'])) > 11){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill with valid (max)11 digit phone number excluding spaces'));
    exit;
}

$to      = 'name@domain.com';
$subject = 'Guide has been downloaded';
$message = "Some one at your website just downloaded the guide with following details. \r\n \r\n";
$message .= 'Name: '.$_GET['name']." \r\n";
$message .= 'Email: '.$_GET['email']." \r\n";
$message .= 'PostCode: '.$_GET['postcode']." \r\n";
$message .= 'Phone: '.$_GET['phone']." \r\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$_GET['email']. "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$_GET['email']. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> true, 'message' => 'Thank You'));
    exit;
?>
```

Please if someone can point out the issue and help me sort it out.. would really appreciate it.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code: You told it to enter data in to the db irrelevant of checks.
I have not changed any of your code other than the location of the datbase insertion. Any other mistakes havent been addressed

```
<?php error_reporting(0); 

if(empty($_GET)){ 
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the complete form'));     
    exit; 
} 

// download function 
if(isset($_GET['file'])){ 
$filename = 'Guide.pdf'; // set absolute relative path to this file 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/download/"; 
$fullpath = $path.$filename; 
// required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored 
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) 
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); 
header("Pragma: public"); // required 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"'); 
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($fullpath)); 
readfile($fullpath); 
} 

if(!isset($_GET['name']) || empty($_GET['name'])){ 
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the name')); 
    exit; 
}elseif(strlen($_GET['name']) < 3){ 
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the valid name (minimum 3 cherecters)')); 
    exit; 
} 
if(!isset($_GET['email']) || empty($_GET['email'])){ 
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the email')); 
    exit; 
}elseif(!ereg('[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+', $_GET['email'])){ 
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Invalid email address')); 
    exit; 
} 
if(!isset($_GET['postcode']) || empty($_GET['postcode']) || strlen($_GET['postcode']) < 3){ 
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the postcode')); 
    exit; 
} 
if(!isset($_GET['phone']) || empty($_GET['phone']) || strlen($_GET['phone']) < 11){ 
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill the phone')); 
    exit; 
}elseif(strlen(str_replace(' ', '',$_GET['phone'])) > 11){ 
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> false, 'message' => 'Please Fill with valid (max)11 digit phone number excluding spaces')); 
    exit; 
} 

$to      = 'name@domain.com'; 
$subject = 'Guide has been downloaded'; 
$message = "Some one at your website just downloaded the guide with following details. \r\n \r\n"; 
$message .= 'Name: '.$_GET['name']." \r\n"; 
$message .= 'Email: '.$_GET['email']." \r\n"; 
$message .= 'PostCode: '.$_GET['postcode']." \r\n"; 
$message .= 'Phone: '.$_GET['phone']." \r\n"; 

$headers = 'From: '.$_GET['email']. "\r\n" . 
    'Reply-To: '.$_GET['email']. "\r\n" . 
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    echo json_encode(array('status'=> true, 'message' => 'Thank You')); 
//database insertion 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql_user","mysql_pwd"); 
if (!$con) 
{ 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_select_db("mysql_database", $con); 
$sql="INSERT INTO formdata (name, email, postcode, phone) VALUES ('$_GET[name]','$_GET[email]','$_GET[postcode]','$_GET[phone]')"; 
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) 
{ 
die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_close($con); 

?>
```

Comment: now its all working as i wanted.. coming to the second phaze.. if someone can point me in the right direction.. so if i wanted to create a php file while will display the table created above? how can i do it? i mean to display all the users who downloaded our guide in a readable format.. in short output the tables in php?

Comment: Thats a new question, have a go at the code, and post it as a new question.  As the anwer was right, dont forget to mark the answer as right.